# Form not sending the way created

Tags: outlook

I am trying to create a survey template in Outlook for the first time. So I created a very basic template which has one question and three radio buttons to choose from. When I use Tools\Forms\Design a Form it looks fine however, when I try and test it by going to File\New\Choose Form and emailing myself a copy I receive my standard message page (nothing like the form I just created!). Can anyone explain what I am doing incorrectly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Quote](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/):

> Common email clients share a propensity to distrust forms in email
>   messages. But they differed greatly in how they handled the intruding
>   forms.

Because of this I suggest to not use forms in emails as you might not get the expected result.

Comment: Does a form template need to be published before it will send properly?